# Java While loop won't loop and prints forever

Tags: java

I'm doing this quiz project in java for school and I'm stuck.

The problem is that I have to do a while loop and check if the users answer matches correct answers, then print out if they were correct with a score. In the while loop once it matches the userAnswer to one of the answers in the if statement then it keeps printing out the same statement forever. So, I tried to fix this using a boolean in the if statement to only print once. But doing this breaks the while loop because it doesn't do anything after printing out the statement and the program just stops doing anything, as in it doesnt come up with an error or end but it just shows up blank. How can I continue the while loop to ask the question over and over until I type "X" to end looping without having the infinite printing.

Thank you in advance.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class miniProject {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        quiz_Check();
        System.exit(0);
    }

    //this method asks the user question and saves the answer
    public static String askUser() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Name one of the 2020 US election candidate");
        String userAnswer = scanner.nextLine();
        return userAnswer;
    }

    //this method checks the users answer and evaluates if they were correct and then gives them a score and prints out if they were correct
    public static int quiz_Check(){

        String userAnswer = askUser();
        int score = 0;

        while(!askUser().equals("X")){
            if ((userAnswer.equals("Kanye West"))){
                score+=2;
                System.out.println("Correct Answer! "+ userAnswer +" is worth 2 points!");
            }
            else if((userAnswer.equals("Donald Trump"))){
                score+=42;
                System.out.println("Correct Answer! "+ userAnswer +" is worth 42  points");
            }
            else if((userAnswer.equals("Joe Biden"))){
                score+=78;
                System.out.println("Correct Answer! "+ userAnswer+" is worth 78 points");
            }
            else{
                score+=100;
            }
        }

        return score;
    }

    //this method prints out the score
    public static void quiz_Score(){

        int score=quiz_Check();

        System.out.println("The score is: "+score);

        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you loop conditional never  changes:

```
 while(!userAnswer.equals("X"))
```

will be either false, or always true.

Based on your current design, you just need to keep asking for an answer until the user return 'X'

```
public static int quiz_Check(){

     int score = 0;
     System.out.println("Name one of the 2020 US election candidate");
     while(!askUser().equals("X")){
         if ((userAnswer.equals("Kanye West"))){
            score+=2;
            System.out.println("Correct Answer! "+ userAnswer +" is worth 2 points!");
        }
        else if((userAnswer.equals("Donald Trump"))){
            score+=42;
            System.out.println("Correct Answer! "+ userAnswer +" is worth 42  points");
        }
        else if((userAnswer.equals("Joe Biden"))){
            score+=78;
            System.out.println("Correct Answer! "+ userAnswer+" is worth 78 points");
        }
        else{
            score+=100;
        }
    }

    return score;
}
```

and

```
public static String askUser() {
    return new Scanner(System.in).scanner.nextLine();
}
```